# not able to run "phablet-flash -b -l" and so install ubuntu touch on my galaxy nexus

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31
sdk updated.
Someone tell to change adb secure line from 1 to 0. if this is the solution, please tell me how to do it! android version 4.2.2
many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. It might be very helpful if you could explain a little bit in detail, what happens when you run “phablet-flash -b -l”. Error msgs, etc. Did you follow the installation/flash procedure thoroughly. Can you run "adb devices"? And what's the output of that?

Comment: yes!! i ran adb devices and it answered offline, all the time it was offline!

Comment: i followed this guide:https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install

Comment: sorry but I tought yours wasn't a message of a user...sorry for the late!

Answer (score -1):

Read this, that should help. Have a nice day!
http://www.wugfresh.com/faq/how-to-fix-adb-device-is-listed-as-offline-on-android-4-2-2/

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]. Please, don't just provide a link as answer, we search for high quality answers. Please read [answer] for more information.